# creating an indexed dummy variable as a predictor in OLS

Tags: regression, time-series, categorical-data, least-squares

I am performing on OLS with two predictors and a response variable. The data is a time series of 450 days approximately. There is an irregular pattern in my response variable - it sometimes arbitrarily does not respond to the predictors. I wanted to capture this irregularity in a dummy variable and use it as one of the predictors.

1) Is this a good approach? 
2) How can I create a dummy variable which is an index of the irregularity in `R`?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be what is called analysis of residuals?

Comment: theoretically, it is what I am trying to do but capturing it as a regressor and deriving a co-efficient might make model more robust ?

Comment: You're deriving the values of the new predictor from the response? How did you go about doing this? If you're doing what it sounds like, I don't think this would be useful.

Comment: no . . not deriving value of a new predictor from the response. But asking if there is someway in which I can create a new predictor which is like an index that captures the irregularity in my response. like can we decompose it as a time series object to derive a trend or irregular component ?